# How to solve dpkg: error processing archive?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, themes

I am getting this error while upgrading using `sudo apt-get upgrade -y`. How to solve this?

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gtk-theme_5.2.0~1586289568~20.04~f35b83b~ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack)
```

Comment: Please provide your OS/release details, also provide the paste & details inside your actual question text.  Title details may not be readable to all viewers of the question as we don't all use desktop/browsers that show the title when viewing your question (You say "I am getting this error* but don't actually show an error in the question).  Have you tried `sudo apt -f install` and what messages did you get when you tried it?